# Can I use CLIMutable records with EntityFramework in an update scenario?

Tags: entity-framework, f#

I am trying to use F# record types with the CLIMutable attribute as entities with Entity Framework. Selecting entities, and adding new entities works fine, but there is a problem with updating entities. Apparently I cannot use the assignment operator (<-) to assign a value to the field of a mutable record type.

Is there any way to make an assignment to the field of an existing record?

```
[<CLIMutable>]
[<Table("UserProfile")>]
type UserProfile = {
    [<Key>]
    Id : int    
    Username : string }

type Context() =
    inherit DbContext(connectionString)

    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable private _users : DbSet<UserProfile>

    member this.Users
        with get() = this._users and set(v) = this._users <- v

let updateUsername id username =
    use context = new Context()
    let user = context.Users.Find(id : int)
    user.Username <- username //This line does not compile
    context.SaveChanges()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx):

```
type Car = {
    Make : string
    Model : string
    mutable Odometer : int
    }
let myCar = { Make = "Fabrikam"; Model = "Coupe"; Odometer = 108112 }
myCar.Odometer <- myCar.Odometer + 21
```

The `CLIMutable` attribute is there so that frameworks etc can populate records.  If you need to modify the record yourself, you simply need to inform the F# compiler that you want to be able to update that field.